# Moving the page title on archive-product page in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

On my WooCommerce shop page (archive-product template), I'm trying to move the page title so that it is outside the site-inner area and rather in the header area, like it is on the other pages on my site. I want to add a full-width image behind it, so I need it outside the current hook that it's in.

I'd also like to be able to make this edit in my **`functions.php`** file so that I don't have to worry about WooCommerce upgrades.

Here's the code on the archive-product page that's controlling the title:

```
get_header( 'shop' ); ?>

<?php
    /**
     * woocommerce_before_main_content hook.
     *
     * @hooked woocommerce_output_content_wrapper - 10 (outputs opening divs for the content)
     * @hooked woocommerce_breadcrumb - 20
     */
    do_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content' );
?>

    <?php if ( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_show_page_title', true ) ) : ?>

        <h1 class="page-title"><?php woocommerce_page_title(); ?></h1>

    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php
        /**
         * woocommerce_archive_description hook.
         *
         * @hooked woocommerce_taxonomy_archive_description - 10
         * @hooked woocommerce_product_archive_description - 10
         */
        do_action( 'woocommerce_archive_description' );
    ?>
```

What can I add to my functions.php to override where the page title is now? You can see the [page in question here.](http://mossandblue.com/shop)

Answer (score 1):

> First, it's possible to [**Override WooCommerce templates via a Theme**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/) *(better with a child theme)* avoiding the problem of woocommerce updates.

To remove the WooCommerce archives pages title you can use the code below:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_show_page_title', '__return_false' );
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

---

> Then you will have to edit your **`header.php`** theme template to make the page title appear on the shop page just as you want *(the best solution is to create a child theme and copy **`header.php`** from parent theme to child theme)*. 
>   You can also use [**WooCommerce conditional tags**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/conditional-tags/#section-4) to target the Shop page and other WooCommerce archives pages…

Answer (score 0):

1. Copy `wp-content\plugins\woocommerce\templates\archive-product.php`
   to `wp-content\themes\your-theme\woocommerce\archive-product.php`
2. Change code:

```html
<?php
/**
 * The Template for displaying product archives, including the main shop page which is a post type archive
 *
 * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/archive-product.php.
 *
 * HOWEVER, on occasion WooCommerce will need to update template files and you
 * (the theme developer) will need to copy the new files to your theme to
 * maintain compatibility. We try to do this as little as possible, but it does
 * happen. When this occurs the version of the template file will be bumped and
 * the readme will list any important changes.
 *
 * @see      https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
 * @author   WooThemes
 * @package  WooCommerce/Templates
 * @version     3.3.0
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
 exit;
}

get_header( 'shop' );

/**
 * Hook: woocommerce_before_main_content.
 *
 * @hooked woocommerce_output_content_wrapper - 10 (outputs opening divs for the content)
 * @hooked woocommerce_breadcrumb - 20
 * @hooked WC_Structured_Data::generate_website_data() - 30
 */

?>
    <header class="woocommerce-products-header">
        <?php if ( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_show_page_title', true ) ) : ?>
            <h1 class="woocommerce-products-header__title page-title"><?php woocommerce_page_title(); ?></h1>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php
        /**
         * Hook: woocommerce_archive_description.
         *
         * @hooked woocommerce_taxonomy_archive_description - 10
         * @hooked woocommerce_product_archive_description - 10
         */
        do_action( 'woocommerce_archive_description' );
        ?>
    </header>
<?php

do_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content' );

if ( have_posts() ) {

 /**
  * Hook: woocommerce_before_shop_loop.
  *
  * @hooked wc_print_notices - 10
  * @hooked woocommerce_result_count - 20
  * @hooked woocommerce_catalog_ordering - 30
  */
 do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop' );

 woocommerce_product_loop_start();

 if ( wc_get_loop_prop( 'total' ) ) {
  while ( have_posts() ) {
   the_post();

   /**
    * Hook: woocommerce_shop_loop.
    *
    * @hooked WC_Structured_Data::generate_product_data() - 10
    */
   do_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop' );

   wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );
  }
 }

 woocommerce_product_loop_end();

 /**
  * Hook: woocommerce_after_shop_loop.
  *
  * @hooked woocommerce_pagination - 10
  */
 do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop' );
} else {
 /**
  * Hook: woocommerce_no_products_found.
  *
  * @hooked wc_no_products_found - 10
  */
 do_action( 'woocommerce_no_products_found' );
}

/**
 * Hook: woocommerce_after_main_content.
 *
 * @hooked woocommerce_output_content_wrapper_end - 10 (outputs closing divs for the content)
 */
do_action( 'woocommerce_after_main_content' );

/**
 * Hook: woocommerce_sidebar.
 *
 * @hooked woocommerce_get_sidebar - 10
 */
do_action( 'woocommerce_sidebar' );

get_footer( 'shop' );
```